# Error from Assigning Vector List Element to Variable

Tags: r

Okay, I'm getting a really strange error when trying to assign a list element to a new variable in R.  I run the following code:

```
findLine <- function(datapoints) {
    print(datapoints[[2]])
    print(is.vector(datapoints[[2]]))
    heatUse <- dataPoints[[2]]
```

print(datapoints[[2]]) returns [1] 4.00 4.92 5.15 5.01 5.23 4.95 5.32 0.22

print(is.vector(datapoints[[2]])) returns TRUE

But when it tries to execute heatUse <- dataPoints[[2]], I get

"Error in findLine(doublePSet[[1]]) : object 'dataPoints' not found"

As for where datapoints came from:

First, there is a function called findPoints that returns a 2-element list containing vectors, using pointVecs <- list(dDays, hTotal)

This function is called using

```
doublePSet <- c(list(findPoints(daysDHP,base)),list(findPoints(daysER,base)) )
```

So doublePSet is a 2-element list of 2-element lists

findLine is called using

```
doubleLSet <- c(list(findLine(doublePSet[[1]])),list(findLine(doublePSet[[2]])) )
```

So the first findLine call is passed the first 2-element list of vectors in doublePSet.  Thus, datapoints is a 2 element list of vectors.

So, any ideas why this error is occuring?  Given that dataPoints[[2]] displays properly and is a vector, I'm stumped.

Comment: Please show some sample data and a sample run and the desired result

Comment: Are you sure `dataPoints` exists and it's not called `datapoints`? Capitalization matters.

Comment: Wow, it was the capitalization all along.  Can't believe I missed that.  Thanks!